# Populate dropdownlist with DB table names

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to populate a dropdownlist with the name of the tables in my SQL database.
This is my code attempt but nothing is happening when I call it and the dropdownlist stays empty.

```
public  void FillDropDownList()
    {
        String connString = "myConnectionString";

        //**STRING UPDATED**
        String Query = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables";

        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, cn);
                SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(myReader);
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                //to be completed
            }

            radDropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
            radDropDownList1.ValueMember = "TABLES_NAME";
            radDropDownList1.DisplayMember = "TABLES_NAME";
        }
    }
```

How can I populate the dropdownlist with the above query?

Comment: Have you checked your dataTable. is there any records exists?

Comment: Make sure your `Postback`.,

Comment: @vallabha yes, I have data in there. I think the problem is with the displayMember and ValueMember. I have used a different query that I have updated in my question

Comment: @SonerGönül if I run the update query straight in the DB would return what I need. I checked. What I get in the dropdown is System.Data.RowView... and not the tables name!

Comment: If you are using the same code as posted the below answer that i had given should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the string that you are using as `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`  , please replace the below

```
 radDropDownList1.ValueMember = "TABLES_NAME";
 radDropDownList1.DisplayMember = "TABLES_NAME";
```

with

```
 radDropDownList1.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";
 radDropDownList1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
```

Comment: @user3855329 please mark it as answer, so that others can get benefited

Answer (score 2):

You query is not correct, it needs to be

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```